# Create imagebrush, bitmap and writeablebitmap from an url

Tags: image, azure, windows-phone-8.1, azure-blob-storage, imagebrush

Hey I have a windows phone 8.1 app using the silverlight API.
I am downloading this image from my blob storage.

[image: Image to be downloaded]

The image is coming from a link like this: https://[service].blob.core.windows.net/[imagename].png and the image can be showned and downloaded in multiple browsers, just using the URI.

I now want to use this as a imagebrush based on the imageuri from the blobstorage:

```
// If we have a returned SAS.
                BitmapImage myOnlineImage = new BitmapImage();
                myOnlineImage.UriSource = new Uri(uploadImage.ImageUri, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
                //ImageOnlineTest.Source = myOnlineImage;
                var imageBrush = new ImageBrush
                {
                    ImageSource = myOnlineImage,
                    Stretch = Stretch.None
                };
                var source = FindChildShieldCanvas(CanvasImage, imageBrush);

                WriteableBitmap wbm = new WriteableBitmap((BitmapImage)myOnlineImage);
                ImageOnlineTest.Source = wbm;
```

The `myOnlineImage` is not created correctly, at least I cannot convert the image to a writeablebitmapimage (getting a null exception from the conversion), and in addition the imagebrush is empty, i.e. null. But as far as I know this is the way to do it?

**So basicly**

How do I create an `imagebrush` based on an url to a https site?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up solving the issue myself:

Remember to add `using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;`

```
// If we have a returned SAS.
                BitmapImage myOnlineImage = new BitmapImage();

                //myOnlineImage.UriSource = new Uri(uploadImage.ImageUri, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
                using (var webCLient = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient())
                {
                    webCLient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "bot");
                    var responseStream = await webCLient.GetBufferAsync(new Uri(uploadImage.ImageUri, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
                    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();//responseStream.ToArrayAsStream().ReadAsync());

                    memoryStream.Write(responseStream.ToArray(), 0, responseStream.ToArray().Length);
                    memoryStream.Position = 0;
                    myOnlineImage.SetSource(memoryStream);

                }
                //ImageOnlineTest.Source = myOnlineImage;
                var imageBrush = new ImageBrush
                {
                    ImageSource = myOnlineImage,
                    Stretch = Stretch.None
                };
                var source = FindChildShieldCanvas(CanvasImage, imageBrush);

                WriteableBitmap wbm = new WriteableBitmap((BitmapImage)myOnlineImage);
```

This code works, both for the imagebrush and writeablebitmap

Answer (score 3):

To create a bitmap from an image you have to start the initialization of the bitmap object prior to setting the URL.

```
    BitmapImage myOnlineImage = new BitmapImage();
    myOnlineImage.BeginInit();
    myOnlineImage.UriSource = new Uri(uploadImage.ImageUri, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
    myOnlineImage.EndInit();

    var imageBrush = new ImageBrush
    {
        ImageSource = myOnlineImage,
        Stretch = Stretch.None
    };
    var source = FindChildShieldCanvas(CanvasImage, imageBrush);

    WriteableBitmap wbm = new WriteableBitmap((BitmapImage)myOnlineImage);
    ImageOnlineTest.Source = wbm;
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. It seems like `BeginInit` and `EndInit` is not available on windows phone 8.1 silverlight?

Comment: Looking at the documentation it says the "BitmapImage won't be ready for use until it raises an ImageOpened event".  Although it looks like you successfully switched to the SetSource method.

Comment: Tried many different things like listening for the event and other, but it did not seem to work properly :/

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with C# in the following way, replace the appropriate code with your fields.

```
Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle();
rectangle.StrokeThickness = 10;
rectangle.Height = 200;
rectangle.Width = 100;
rectangle.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, 100d);
rectangle.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, 100d);
rectangle.Fill = new ImageBrush(new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"C:\User\xiaorui.dong\Pictures\profile.jpeg")));
```

Comment: I tried this in the star, but with no success. My question is if this is done within a wp 8.1 silverlight project or what project type?