# Download image in windows phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

i want to download images from specified Uri s and show it in Grid View

```
<GridView>
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
             <Image Width="150" Height="150" Source="{Binding Source={}}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

Comment: use `Uri` to download image and set it into `ImageSource` property of your `Image` tag from code behind

Comment: Have you looked at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33854553/create-imagebrush-bitmap-and-writeablebitmap-from-an-url ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a model class, set the following property & bind it to the image element.

```
Public class YourClass
{

public string imageuri { get ; set ; } //web image uri

public BitmapImage ImageUrl
        {
            get
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(imageuri))
                {
                    BitmapImage bmi = new BitmapImage();
                    bmi.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache;
                    bmi.UriSource = new Uri(imageuri, UriKind.Absolute);
                    return bmi;
                }
                return null;
            }
        }
}

<GridView>
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
             <Image Width="150" Height="150" Source="{Binding ImageUrl,Mode=Twoway}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```